# How do I receive a return from a function after a button click in PyQT?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am tinkering with interfaces in PyQT and have created a situation where I am calling a function that returns a value after a button has been clicked but I don't know how to put that response into a variable.

```
accCreateBtn.clicked.connect(outcome = credCreate())
```

The above obviously doesn't work as I get a type error from `connect` and putting it at the beginning

```
outcome = accCreateBtn.clicked.connect(credCreate())
```

only gives me the connection:

> <PyQt5.QtCore.QMetaObject.Connection object at 0x000001DA870EBA50>

Does anyone know a good way around this?

Answer (score 0):

`connect` takes a function as parameter. So you can create a function to save the response.

```
def handle_click():
    outcome = credCreate()
    ...

accCreateBtn.clicked.connect(handle_click)
```

**Note**: No round brackets, because you don't pass the return of the function. You pass the function as parameter.